# How to prove that $\mathbb{z}\alpha +\mathbb{z}$ has not a minimum positive element

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that infinite subgrups of $\mathbb{S}^1 $ are dense. I've proved that it suffices to show that $\mathbb{Z}\alpha +\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R} $ (with $\alpha $ irrational). I've found a way to prove the later statement by showing that   $\mathbb{Z}\alpha +\mathbb{Z}$ has not minimum elements. In this ([Show that there are only two types of subgroups in R , either Discrete or Dense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211750/show-that-there-are-only-two-types-of-subgroups-in-r-either-discrete-or-dense) )question someone prove it by assuming that a minimum element $x$ of the set $\mathbb{Z}\alpha +\mathbb{Z}$ must verify $nx=1 $ and $mx=\alpha $ for some $m,n\in \mathbb{Z} $.

I was trying to prove his assumption but i can't. I need some help from you. 
Thanks :)

Comment: If $\mathbb S^1$ is compact and the subgroup is not finite there must be  a convergent sequence of subgroup elements, from which you can derive the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean a minimum **positive** element of $\Bbb Z\alpha+\Bbb Z$.

If there is such an element $x$, then every element of the *group*
$\Bbb Z\alpha+\Bbb Z$ must be an integer multiple of it, since otherwise
one would get an element $y$ in the group with $0<y<x$. In particular
$1$ must be an integer multiple of $x$.